# Close command prompt window when new mail is displayed in Outlook via python

Tags: python-2.7, outlook

I have a python script that is executed from a button in Access. Everything works fine but I cannot seem to get the command prompt window to close until I exit the program I have "called" up. In this instance it is the mail in outlook.

I am automating a mail response. Before sending the mail I want to review it. Once the mail display window is open, I want the python script to end and the console window to close. Right now the python script only ends and closes the window when I close the mail I am reviewing.

It is getting hung up here, at the "last" line of code.

```
newMail.Display(True)
```

I tried putting the following commands at the end of the script with no luck.

```
exit()
sys.exit()
```

Ideas?

I want my Access database to remain open.

Using python 2.7, Access 2010, Outlook 10, and Windows 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call newMail.Display(**false**) - you displayed the inspector modally.

Comment: That did the trick. I could have sworn I tried that but I guess only thought about trying that.